# Can I cook Tandoori chicken, chicken kebab, grilled chicken, and barbecue chicken on the gas stove?

Tags: chicken, grilling, barbecue, kebab

Suppose I change the spice mixes for those four types of nearly identical recipes.

All these items are generally cooked either in an earth oven or on charcoal.

Can I cook them on a gas stove? If so, apart from changing spices, what should I do to make them look different so that people can distinguish those dishes and don't know that they were cooked on a gas stove?

Comment: "Apart from the spice and the kind of oven or stove"?  What other differences do you want?  What's the difference between a watermelon and a cucumber, other than flavor, size, and texture?

Comment: As FuzzyChef said, there is no "the difference" without context. The default culinary difference is by taste, and they obviously taste differently.

Comment: I think the other thing to note is that they are terms from different food cultures, so are associated with different occasions and accompaniments as well as generally being made differently. They are also all very broad terms in themselves, each covering a wide range.

Comment: I'm sorry but your edit leaves me somewhat confused. Why would you not be able to cook these dishes on a gas stove? Maybe you can add a bit more information in your question about what you're trying to understand?

Comment: Are you planning to make all of these dishes at the same time?  Why?  What makes you think they are "nearly identical"?  What recipes are you using?

Comment: @FuzzyChef, *Are you planning to make all of these dishes at the same time? Why?* --- Coz, I am arranging a family gathering. Different people requested these different dishes. *What makes you think they are "nearly identical"?* --- All are burned, that's why. *What recipes are you using?* --- I am using readymade spice mix packets.

Comment: Aha, I begin to see the problem.  There are, indeed, more differences between those dishes than "spice mix packets" can cover.  For example, Tandoori, kebab, and BBQ chicken are usually marinated before being cooked, and that marinade involves more than just spices.  The meat is also cut differently.  If you're constraining yourself to spice packets, you will indeed find that you have 4 chicken dishes that seem nearly identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spicing is a red-herring.  It doesn't matter all that much for your question.  Aside from the kabab, all can be cooked in the oven, and finished on a grill pan on the stove top....or a regular cast iron pan, if you don't care about grill marks.  The kebab can be cooked entirely on the grill pan.  While you won't get flavor from smoke and drippings hitting coals, you can achieve the grill marks and appealing burnt part.  They are going to look different, because they are different recipes.  Tandoori chicken tends to take on the color of turmeric, kababs will be chunked and probably on a skewer, BBQ chicken will likely be sauced...